# Is App Maker hipaa compliant when is used with cloud sql

Tags: google-app-maker, hipaa

App Maker is hosted on app engine which is hipaa compliant. So when i use Cloud SQL which is hipaa compliant as well, can i use app maker for hipaa compliant applications in our company?

Comment: Sorry about this question, but I ask this question the G Suite Support and they told my the best option is to ask this question to the developer team through stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly the service itself I don't think it is hipaa compliance, it could be hosted on App Engine which is hipaa compliance but I guess that App Engine works as hipaa compliance when you use it in your personal projects. Maybe you can find helpful details here https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/gsuite.google.com/en//intl/en/terms/2015/1/hipaa_implementation_guide.pdf, I would suggest to create a case with the API/App Maker team trough your Admin Console.